# Does this past perfect tense mean ‘completion’ or ‘continuity’ of his doing?

Tags: tenses

> In years to come, Harry would never quite remember how he **had managed**
>   to get through his exams when he half expected Voldemort to come
>   bursting through the door at any moment. Yet the days crept by, and
>   there could be no doubt that Fluffy was still alive and well behind
>   the locked door.
>
> It was sweltering hot, especially in the large classroom where they
>   did their written papers. They had been given special, new quills for
>   the exams, which had been bewitched with an Anti-Cheating spell.
>   (Harry Potter)

Does the past perfect tense mean ‘completion’ or ‘continuity’ of his doing? Consulting [MacMillan dictionary](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/get-through), if I understand ‘get through’ as ‘deal with something difficult,’ it seems like having the meaning of ‘continuity,’ yet as ‘finish doing something,’ it seems like ‘completion.’

Comment: I think it's General Reference that if the writer had intended "continuity" it would have been *"remember how he **had been managing** to get through"*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means Harry, in the future, looking back at his current exams (which will have been long completed at that point).  And *get through* does indeed mean *to complete* usually used when *getting through to completion* takes some effort or perseverence.

Answer (score 0):

I would say completed at the time of the not quite remembering in years to come. That is, at the time the memory couldn't be had, but that memory was of a thing that at the time it was happening was a continuing thing. Does that make sense? If he could remember, he would have a completed memory of a continuing getting through the exams.